# ¿Cómo mejoro este programa para que agregue el último elemento al arreglo automáticamente cuando dicho elemento es el último que queda en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, array, while, diccionarios

El siguiente programa permite al usuario definir el orden en el cual los nombres de llaves (elementos) de `the_dictionary_list` serán insertados en `Keys_input`:

```
the_dictionary_list = {'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'], 'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'], 'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'], 'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}


# creating an empty list
Keys_input = []
# number of elements
n = len(the_dictionary_list)
i = 0
print('\n')
print('The following "keys" represent the name of the folders in the current path')
while True:
    AllKeysNames = the_dictionary_list.keys()
    print('\033[46m'+str(AllKeysNames)+'\033[0m')
    ele = input("\033[0;37;40mNow It's time to define the order in which the Cartesian Products will be made, tell me which valid key you want me to set now:\033[0m ")
    if ele in the_dictionary_list and ele not in Keys_input:
        Keys_input.append(ele) # adding the element
        i += 1
        print(f'\033[0;37;42mThe array has been updated, its current storage is the following {Keys_input}\033[0m')
        if i == n:
            print("\u001b[45mThe array is now full, let's continue with the next step\033[0m")
            break
    else:
        if ele not in the_dictionary_list:
            print('\u001b[43mPlease, type only valid key names\033[0m')
        if ele in Keys_input:
            print('\u001b[43mStop, that key IS ALREADY SAVED in the array, try with a different valid one\033[0m')
            print(f'\u001b[45mCurrent storage of the array is the following {Keys_input}\033[0m')
```

Ahora, suponga que el usuario escoge el siguiente orden para los elementos en `Keys_input`:

```
['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas', 'Puas']
```

Cómo podría el programa de arriba ser mejorado para añadir automáticamente el último elemento disponible (en este caso `'Puas'`) al arreglo cuando no hay más nombres de llaves disponibles? Quiero decir, justo después de que el arreglo `Keys_input` este actualizado como se muestra:

```
['Fondo', 'Cuerpo', 'Ojos', 'Color', 'Pinzas']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código se puede simplificar mucho (y a la vez ser más amigable para el usuario) si la lista de claves disponibles en lugar de tener siempre todas las claves tiene solo las que aún no hayan sido elegidas.

De ese modo en cada iteración del bucle al usuario se le presentan sólo las opciones válidas (en vez de todas). Y además tenemos fácil detectar cuándo ya han sido elegidas todas menos una: cuando la lista de opciones tenga longitud 1. El bucle `while` entonces no sería infinito, sino que se basaría en esa condición. Mientras haya más de una opción disponible se sigue en el bucle. Cuando sólo queda una disponible, se sale del bucle y se añade la que quedaba.

Esta sería la implementación (respetando en lo posible tu código y mensajes originales):

```py
the_dictionary_list = {'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'], 'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'], 'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'], 'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}


# creating an empty list
Keys_input = []
AllowedKeysNames = list(the_dictionary_list.keys())
# number of elements
print('\n')
print('The following "keys" represent the name of the folders in the current path')
while len(AllowedKeysNames) > 1:
    print('\033[46mValid options: '+str(AllowedKeysNames)+'\033[0m')
    ele = input("\033[0;37;40mNow It's time to define the order in which the Cartesian Products will be made, tell me which valid key you want me to set now:\033[0m ")
    if ele not in AllowedKeysNames:
        print('\u001b[43mPlease, type only valid key names\033[0m')
        continue  # Go to while
    Keys_input.append(ele)
    AllowedKeysNames.remove(ele)  # Remove from allowed
    print(f'\033[0;37;42mThe array has been updated, its current storage is the following {Keys_input}\033[0m')
# Add the last key    
Keys_input.append(AllowedKeysNames[0])
print(f'\033[0;37;42mLet me add the last key, the final storage is the following {Keys_input}\033[0m')
print("\u001b[45mThe array is now full, let's continue with the next step\033[0m")
```

Observa cómo además se simplifica mucho la detección de si el usuario ha elegido una opción correcta. Basta mirar si está entre las disponibles y no es necesario mirar si ya fue elegida (si lo hubiera sido, ya no estaría entre las disponibles), y ya no son necesarias tampoco las variables `i` ni `n`.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! @abulafia

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví, después de haber agregado el penúltimo elemento al arreglo, el programa usará un ciclo for para recorrer el diccionario, y evaluará qué llave del diccionario no está dentro del arreglo, aquella que no esté (siempre será la última), será añadida automáticamente por el programa, luego de esto, rompe el bucle `while True` del código original

```
if i == (n-1):
    for key in the_dictionary_list:
        if key not in Keys_input:
            Keys_input.append(key)
            print(f'\033[0;37;42mLet me add the last key, the final storage is the following {Keys_input}\033[0m')
    print("\u001b[45mThe array is now full, let's continue with the next step\033[0m")
    break
```

Comment: Podrías explicar como esto resuelve tu problema?

Comment: @Christian Hecho, mejoré la descripción de la respuesta como solución.